# Is there a standard way of programming in HTML5/js/PHP/CSS to create reusable objects?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, github

I have created (in my free time) a html page that uses PHP to create my dynamic object.
This page calls my javascript to receive input from the user with AJAX.
My object uses the AJAX for input (PHP does a $_GET) and my object will then open a connection to my PDO mySQL database perform a query and receive the detail. With the detail it displays my object and echos HTML5 and I use CSS to do some nice features.

It is working fine. I've learnt so much (CSS is wonderful), but compared to other programming languages, this is very similar to learn, yet sooo different!
I find it is different in the way that... for anything I want to do, there are always **many many** different ways of doing it. Due to this being a group of languages functioning together (PHP, javascript, CSS3, and HTML5).

I've somehow avoided jQuery for the moment, as I'm learning and preferred to do everything the hard way. However I have noticed that a lot of these plugins, like for a barchart for example is created in javascript and given the data there too in the form of an array.

Now I want a second page that will do the same as the first, but access different data and possibly do different things, but it will be a very similar display.
So I want to be able to use my object again and just to give it different parameters, different inputs etc... as if I have just used a plugin. So now I'm thinking of instantiating this in js and feeding the data in from there instead.
I just want some good guidance as I'm starting out and the more I learn the more vast this becomes :)

So this is where my question is:
Q. Is there a standard way of programming in HTML5/js/PHP/CSS to create reusable objects?
References and expertise/experience is welcome, I don't want to start a debate, please. I'd like a standard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It is unclear exactly what you're asking but here is my answer to what I understood.*

### Server Side Organization:

If you were to create a big project I highly advise you to use a `PHP framework` ( [symphony](http://symfony.com/), [codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter), etc ), now if you're not then consider the following:

**1. Follow MVC structure**

[image: MVC structure]

The MVC structure can be represented multiple different ways. However, keeping it simple, you can do this by creating 3 folders ( **controller, model, view** ).

Each folder will consist of different php files with a specific job.

- Controller:

> A controller is the link between a user and the system. It provides
>   the user with input by arranging for relevant views to present
>   themselves in appropriate places on the screen. It provides means for
>   user output by presenting the user with menus or other means of giving
>   commands and data. The controller receives such user output,
>   translates it into the appropriate messages and pass these messages on
>   to one or more of the views.

Think of a controller as the police. Checks to see if the client request is legit ( ***especially when it comes to form validation*** ). When a controller validates the request it calls upon a model (optional: depending if you need to get/set information and work with a database ) and then a view.

- Model:

> Models represent knowledge. A model could be a single object (rather
>   uninteresting), or it could be some structure of objects.
>
> There should be a one-to-one correspondence between the model and its
>   parts on the one hand, and the represented world as perceived by the
>   owner of the model on the other hand.

- View:

> A view is a (visual) representation of its model. It would ordinarily
>   highlight certain attributes of the model and suppress others. It is
>   thus acting as a presentation filter.
>
> A view is attached to its model (or model part) and gets the data
>   necessary for the presentation from the model by asking questions. It
>   may also update the model by sending appropriate messages. All these
>   questions and messages have to be in the terminology of the model, the
>   view will therefore have to know the semantics of the attributes of
>   the model it represents.

The interesting thing with views is that you can break down an HTML page into multiple parts. The main idea is to create a `header.php` and a `footer.php` which will not change much ( depending on the css/js you need ). Then you only need to call on `views` that will fill the main body of the html page.

This is useful so when the client requests the home page you could simply do:

```
include header.php;
include home.php;
include footer.php;
```

Let me know if this was useful.

If you are still unsure about what I am talking about feel free to read the following:

[MVC tutorial 1](https://r.je/mvc-tutorial-real-application-example.html)

[MVC tutorial 2](https://blog.udemy.com/php-mvc-framework-tutorial/)

[Youtube videos tutorial on how to create an MVC structure (basic)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ)

[Youtube videos tutorial on how to create an MVC structure (advanced)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ)

---

[Definition reference here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/)

Comment: wow, well done Grimbode for this answer, very interesting. Much appreciated. I'll check these links and come back to you.

Comment: @xchiltonx I'll add more useful links when I have time to look for them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really 100% sure what you're asking - I'm guessing from your phrasing that you're a little bit of a programming novice.

To answer your question (sort of), the closest thing to a common interface between Javascript, PHP, and (not really) HTML and CSS would be JSON, or Javascript Object Notation.  PHP has libraries to read JSON, and JavaScript reads it natively (better with jQuery).  Some databases (CouchDB, and in a way, MongoDB, Neo4j, etc.) will even store your JSON almost verbatim.

The way you will store the data, in any case, would properly be inside a database, and JSON, regardless of database, would generally be considered the best way to communicate that in between frontend and backend code (which, by the way, sharply differentiates HTML/CSS/JS and PHP).

Comment: Thanks snsdgm. Far from a programming novice, lol. However I am new to this area, last web site I did was 10 years ago, so I really appreciate this. can you give further details on "sharply differentiates HTML/CSS/JS and PHP)"?